# Universal rewrite rule for versioning css/js files?

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

Is there any universal rule to rewrite versions?

`/css/main.123456.css` rewrite to `/css/main.css`

`/css/styles.123456.css` rewrite to `/css/styles.css`

`/js/application.123456.js` rewrite to `/js/application.js`

How should I modify my .htaccess file to add universal versioning for css/js files?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(css|js)/(main|styles|application)\.[0-9]+(\.css|\.js)$ /$1/$2$3 [L]
```

You would actually be better NOT altering the WP `.htaccess` rules and just put your code before it.

That way, Wordpress can make changes without it removing yours

Eg.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^(css|js)/(main|styles|application)\.[0-9]+(\.css|\.js)$ /$1/$2$3 [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like `main.css?123456`, which won't require rewrites, and still bust the browser cache.